# APNs Certificates look different in login keychain

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on generating some replacement APNs server certificates and I'm concerned because when I drag them into the keychain login they look different.  Before the certificates looked like:

```
Apple Production IOS Push Services: com.mycompany.myproduct
```

But now they look like

```
Apple Production IOS Push Services: AB12C3DEF4;AB12C3DEF4
```

where "AB12C3DEF4" is the app prefix.  Has anybody else seen this?  If you've generated an APNs certificate lately, did it look like this?

This is the first time I've done this kind of generation since Apple changed their certificates interface...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw this also.  It appears to be a bug; I filed a radar (also if you search you should see a post I created in the Apple Developer Forums).

In the meantime to make your certificates more findable, make sure to enter a unique name you want to search on in the "name" part of the "**Request a certificate from a certificate authority**" form that generates the request that creates the certificate.  Whatever you enter in the name field will be what the private key is called, so search in keychain will still find your certificate and you'll be able to identify it from the private key name.

Comment: Just as an fyi, you can also "get info" on the certificate in keychain to see the bundle id, for those you created before reading Kendall's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for finding that way to verify the push certificate - too bad the keychain search doesn't seem to use the embedded bundle ID.