# APNs Dev and Prod Certificate issue

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

So, I've done a zillion ios apps with push notifications and I've never run into this:

In the past, when I download the APNS cert (development or production), it showed up in my keychain as:

Apple Development IOS Push Services: com.YYY.ZZZZZZZZ

where YYY.ZZZZZZZ is the bundle identifier.  Now, however, the certificate shows up in the keychain as:

Apple Development IOS Push Services: XXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXX

where XXXXXXXXXX is our apple developer team id.  It does this for each certificate I download, even ones that used to show up correctly, which makes it impossible to tell one from the other.  Strangely, the certificate title looks right in the developer portal.

Additionally, I notice that X-Code is crashing in the Organizer > Provisioning screen when I hit the refresh button in the lower right, but this may be a red herring.

Has anyone run into this and come up with a solution?  I've seen other complaints about this in the last few days on the Apple Developer forums, but not seen any resolutions and I'm hoping the resident stackoverflow geniuses will come to the rescue...

**UPDATE**
To fix the XCode refresh error, run this command in the terminal (per [this post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/796388#796388) at Apple):

```
mkdir ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/OldPortalDBs; mv ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/connect1.apple.com* ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/OldPortalDBs
```

The bizzaro world apns certificate problem still remains, however.

**UPDATE II**
You can "Get Info" in the context menu on the certificate in the keychain to see the bundle identifier, which makes finding the one you're looking for a bit easier.

Comment: To fix the crashing issue check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/15562549/574449

Comment: That did fix the crash issue... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[APNs Certificates look different in login keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959117/apns-certificates-look-different-in-login-keychain) If this is the answer to your question then I ask that you please do some research before posting.

Comment: Sorry I've offended you by missing this.  The link you gave was only posted yesterday and did not show up in my 10 billion stackoverflow searches on this topic that I've done over the last 24 hours.  Enjoy your checked answer.